# find specified numbers in text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm a newbie to the coding world, can someone help me with below scenario?

I need a batch script for windows that does the following:

Scan *.txt file in the “ARAT_Preverification” folder to find if there are any “Error codes” like 503, 504, 511 and 611 (scenario mentioned below);

Below is the sample .txt file where every 1st row has no data and can be ignored; the following rows has data where the batch should scan and find the error codes (if any) between 18-20 characters only, each row has 90 characters including spaces.

> H0001200008143800120918155209
>   D43442371013477773520000001280012091800001
>   D4344237101172222**511**0000000900012091800001
>   D4344237100769292**504**0000007200012091800001

If any *.txt file has the above-mentioned error codes then that file should not be moved to “Verified” Folder if no error codes are found then the .txt file should be moved to "Verified" folder. I got the script below but it doesn't detect the error codes in the file and

```
@echo off
set local
set "beg=^D................"
for %%F in (D:\ARAT\ARAT_Preverification\*.txt) do findstr /r "%beg%503 %beg%504 %beg%511 %beg%611" "%%F" >nul || move "%%F" D:\ARAT\ARAT_Verified
```

Comment: can the code be anywhere in the string, or only at that position?

Comment: the code should scan for the error code between 18-20 characters

Comment: You can use multiple `/C:` switches: `findstr /R /C:"%beg%503" /C:"%beg%504" /C:"%beg%511" /C:"%beg%611"`

Comment: I was mislead by this `each row has 90 characters including spaces` I though the search string also can contain spaces so I recommended to use separate /C switchs. But now I look more closely I see that your script is seemingly does its job as you described: It only moves files that does not contain one of those error codes. But then what's the problem with your code? what do you mean by `it doesn't detect the error codes in the file` ? does it move the wrong files? does not move any files at all? moves all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "source=D:\ARAT\ARAT_Preverification\*.txt"
set "target=D:\ARAT\ARAT_Verified"
set "codes=503 504 511 611"
set "strings=/c:%codes: = /c:%"

if not exist "%target%" md "%target%"

for %%A in ("%source%") do (
    set "found="

    for /f "delims=" %%B in ('findstr %strings% "%%~A"') do (
        if not defined found (
            set "line=%%~B"

            if "!line:~,1!" == "D" (
                for %%C in (%codes%) do (
                    if "!line:~17,3!" == "%%~C" set "found=%%~C"
                )
            )
        )
    )

    if not defined found echo move "%%~A" "%target%"
)
```

Set the error codes to the variable name `codes`.

The variable named `strings` uses variable substitution
to transform the value of `codes` into arguments for use
with `findstr`. View `set /?` about variable substitution.

The target directory is created if not exist.

The initial `for` loop gets each source file.

The nested `for` loop uses `findstr` on the current file
to get the lines matching the strings. Matching lines
are set to variable named `line`. If the 1st character is
`D` then the 2nd nested `for` loop will check for the 3
digit codes from the 17th character. If the code is
detected then the variable named `found` will be defined
with the code.

If the variable named `found` is not defined, then the `move`
operation happens.

Remove the `echo` in front of the `move` command to allow
the actual `move` operation if tested OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%x in (D:\ARAT\ARAT_Preverification\*.txt) do (
set "file=%%x"
for /f %%i in ('type "!file!"') do set "string=%%i"
    set "str=!string:~17,3!"
    for %%a in (504 503 511 611) do if "!str!"=="%%a" echo move "!file!" "D:\ARAT\ARAT_Verified"
)
```

Comment: didn't get the output at all.

Comment: From a single file?

Comment: Yes, basically I get at least 20-25 .txt files in an hour where I need to validate these files and make sure that the error codes are not present in the file. Currently am manually doing it with excel and it is tedious, therefore I want to automate this job by some batch job.

Comment: Yes, I meant to show how to get part of string from a a single file.. Give the edited version a try on all your files please.

Comment: @ Gerhard, thanks for your efforts,  the batch identifies 511 error in 2 different files but not 611 error, secondly it doesn't move the file which has error. Output of the batch looks like: **move"D:\ARAT\ARAT_Preverification\12092018- Test.txt" "D:\ARAT\ARAT_Verified"
move "D:\ARAT\ARAT_Preverification\12092018-Test2.txt" "D:\ARAT\ARAT_Verified"**

Comment: Remove echo before the move command. Echo was placed to test. Please make sure that 611 is at the same position as 504 etc.

Comment: @ Gerhard, the new code works fine, however some file has over 1000 rows where it fails to capture the error code!

Comment: It must get it. Do you have the codes in new lines and same positions each time?